# $f(x,y)\le g(y)$ and $f(x,0)= g(0)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,0) \le g''(0)$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

If
$$
f(x,y)\le g(y)   \\
f(x,0)= g(0) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)=g'(0)
$$
then, whether $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,0) \le g''(0)$ ?  If it is right, how to prove ?

I get this problem from the proof of Theorem 3.5 of  [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07093.pdf). A step of it means the above statement.   I feel it is right, but don't know how to prove.

Comment: @Feng  Yes, you are right, I miss it. Could you tell me how to prove ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why the extra condition is required – see my proof below.

Comment: @ColeG97  Maybe, from the taylor expansion,   we need it.  Thanks your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove this via taking a finite difference approximation of the second derivative. Note that
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,0) = \lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{f(x,y)+f(x,-y)-2f(x,0)}{y^2}.$$
Then, since $\forall y$ $f(x,y)\le g(y)$, and $f(x,0)=g(0)$, we have
$$f(x,y)+f(x,-y)-2f(x,0)\le g(y)+g(-y) - 2g(0)$$
and so
$$\frac{f(x,y)+f(x,-y)-2f(x,0)}{y^2}\le \frac{g(y)+g(-y) - 2g(0)}{y^2}.$$
Taking the limit on both sides as $y\to 0^+$ (which preserves the inequality), we then obtain
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,0)\le g''(0)$$
as desired.